# How to dereference pointer object in C++?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, linked-list, dereference

I am getting error while running this?
`cout << *head << endl;`
Why we cant dereference Object pointer?
Like wise we do in int data type:

```cpp
int obj = 10;
int *ptr = &obj;
cout << *ptr << endl; //This will print the value 10 by dereferencing the operator!
```

But not in object why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};

int main() {
    Node N1(10);
    Node *head = &N1;
   
    cout << &N1 << endl;
    cout << head << endl;
    cout << *head << endl;
    cout << &head << endl;
}
```

Comment: `*head` is the `N1` object, and you don't have any way to output `Node` objects (there's no overloaded `operator<<` function for `Node`).

Comment: Do any of the output statements work as expected? If not, your assumption it might have anything to do with the topic of your question is wrong.  Note that in C++, there is no default output operation for objects like there is in other languages. As new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you're dereferencing a pointer is a red herring: `std::cout << N1 << endl;` will not compile for the same reason.

You need to implement `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& node)` for (at global scope) your `Node` class, which in the function body you'd write something along the lines of

```
{
    os << node.data; // print the data
    return os; // to enable you to 'chain' multiple `<<` in a single cout statement
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is not that you can't dereference the object pointer, rather that you didn't specify how to print that. Pointer to types unknown to the standard library can be printed in the same way no matter what they point to, but for actual objects and object references you have to specify what you want to be shown in the screen. You do that by overloading the `<<` operator for your class, for example:

```
#include <ostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Node &node) {
    return os << "Node(" <<node.data << ")";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `return`.

Comment: "Pointer are printed in the same way no matter what they point to" not true (unfortunately, that would be too easy ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 isn't there a templated overload for any pointer?

Comment: @idclev463035818 you are right, I reworded it to make it less wrong